# Get data from generic type in format {[]}

Tags: java, generics

I'm new in using generic so I'm not sure how to get value inside of it. I'm trying to get `seller id`
from generic but the method I can use is only `.get()`. Can give some pointers on how to get `seller id`?

```
{OtherSellerData: [sellerId : DD00000012, sellerName : TRVE HOLDING BERHAD, details : , sellerBank : 100002050, Status : 2]}
```

The code

```
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        for (ItemWriter delegate : delegates) {
            if (! items.isEmpty()) {
                delegate.write(items);
                log.info("Seller ID {} is saved successfully", items.get(0));
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried the code below but the result is the same

```
        for (T c : items) {
            log.info("Seller ID {} is saved successfully", c);
        }
```

Code in modal class

```
    private String sellerId;
    private String sellerName;
    private String sellerBank;

    public String getSellerId() {
        return sellerId;
    }

    public String getSellerName() {
        return sellerName;
    }

    public String getSellerBank() {
        return sellerBank;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
```

Comment: From which generic you want o get details?

Comment: on ```List<? extends T> items```. I try to get the ```seller id``` only

Comment: But method has void return here. Do you want to update that void?

Comment: No I only need to display the log since this is spring batch job.I update the code

Comment: You need to make a BaseModel to Modal class and the generic should be List<? extends BaseModel>. And this BaseModel should define the method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a IModel interface, with getId() method. As below:

Interface :

```
public interface IModel {

  String getId();
}
```

Model Class :

```
public class Model implements IModel {

  private String sellerBank;

  private String sellerId;

  private String sellerName;

  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return sellerId;
  }

  public String getSellerBank() {
    return sellerBank;
  }

  public String getSellerId() {
    return sellerId;
  }

  public String getSellerName() {
    return sellerName;
  }

}
```

And then use this id in write method as below :

```
@Override
    public void write(List<? extends IModel> items) throws Exception {
        for (ItemWriter delegate : delegates) {
            if (! items.isEmpty()) {
                delegate.write(items);
                log.info("Seller ID {} is saved successfully", items.get(0).getId());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand your answer. Do you mean I can't access seller id if using generic type?

Comment: No, because at compile time type of T is not resolved from method input. Or alternatively you can explicitly cast the object and then use it (not preferred). Or you can create an Generic Class implementation where you will pass the Type of T to resolve the compilation dependency.